# Using Android MediaCodec to codec AAC, fetch result from output buffer, the result count is confusing

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am writing a recording / playing system library for Unity Android. I use MediaCodec for codec between PCM and AAC. I thought if I put one PCM data block containing 1024 samples into MediaCodec's input buffer, then I would finally got one AAC data block. And vice versa in decoding.

But my code does not work as one-to-one way.

The encoder part. Once I inited the encoder, I could fetch one result from its output buffer immediately. I didn't know where's it from without feeding.

The decoder part behavior was more strange. I tested that there were 4 input buffer indexes and 4 output buffer indexes. I fed the input buffers continuously. Then I counted the total feeding input buffers times and obtain result from output buffers times. I tried several times and I found the outcoming count was always 2 less than the feeding count. Seems that there were 2 frames I count not fetch from it.

I am an Android beginner and I don't know why this happended.

I compiled with Android SDK29 and tested on a Sony cellphone.

This is my Encoder code below.

```
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class AACEncoder {
    private static final String TAG = "AACEncoder";

    private int KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT = 1;

    private int KEY_SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;

    private int KEY_BIT_RATE = 128000;

    private MediaCodec mEncoder;

    private int freqIdx = 0xb;

    private Queue<byte[]> m_pcmDataQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private Boolean m_threadRunning=false;
    private AACEncoder.AACThread m_aacEncodeThread;

    private Queue<byte[]> m_aacDataQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private String name;

    public AACEncoder() {
        this.name = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
    }

    /**
     * This is actual param values I set in Unity
     */
    public void initCodec() {
        this.initCodec(16000, 1, 256000);
    }

    protected void initCodec(int sampleRate,int channelCount,int bitRate) {
        KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT = channelCount;
        KEY_SAMPLE_RATE = sampleRate;
        KEY_BIT_RATE = bitRate;
        switch (sampleRate)
        {
            case 96000:
                freqIdx = 0x00;
                break;
            case 88200:
                freqIdx = 0x01;
                break;
            case 64000:
                freqIdx = 0x02;
                break;
            case 48000:
                freqIdx = 0x03;
                break;
            case 44100:
                freqIdx = 0x04;
                break;
            case 32000:
                freqIdx = 0x05;
                break;
            case 24000:
                freqIdx = 0x06;
                break;
            case 22050:
                freqIdx = 0x07;
                break;
            case 16000:
                freqIdx = 0x08;
                break;
            case 12000:
                freqIdx = 0x09;
                break;
            case 11025:
                freqIdx = 0x0a;
                break;
            case 8000:
                freqIdx = 0x0b;
                break;
            case 7350:
                freqIdx = 0x0c;
                break;
        }
        prepare();
        m_aacEncodeThread = new AACEncoder.AACThread();
        m_threadRunning = true;
        m_aacEncodeThread.start();
    }

    private boolean prepare() {
        try {

            String mine = "audio/mp4a-latm";

            mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mine);

            MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC, KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 1);
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, KEY_BIT_RATE);
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 1024 * 1024);

            mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

            Log.d(TAG, "initCodec: " + mEncoder.getName());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        if (mEncoder == null) {
            return false;
        }
        mEncoder.start();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * encode API
     */
    public void encode(byte[] buf, int offset, int length) {
        m_pcmDataQueue.add(buf);
    }

    public void clear() {
        m_pcmDataQueue.clear();
        m_aacDataQueue.clear();
    }

    /**
     * get encoded aac API
     */
    public byte[] getAACData() {
        byte[] output = m_aacDataQueue.poll();
        return output;
    }

    private void encodeAAC(byte[] buf, int offset, int length) {
        if(buf == null || length ==0 || offset < 0 || offset >= buf.length){
            return ;
        }

        long kTimeOutUs = 0;
        try {

            int inputBufIndex = mEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(kTimeOutUs);
            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {

                ByteBuffer dstBuf = mEncoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);//codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex]
                if(dstBuf!=null){

                    dstBuf.clear();

                    dstBuf.put(buf, offset, length);
                    dstBuf.limit(length);

                    mEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, length, 0, 0);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Audio encode error " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void pollEncoderResult() {

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

        long kTimeOutUs = 0;

        int outputBufferIndex = mEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);


        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {

            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = mEncoder.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex);//codecOutputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

            if(outputBuffer != null){

                int byteBufSize = info.size;
                int bytePacketSize =byteBufSize + 7;
                byte[] outData = new byte[bytePacketSize];
                addADTStoPacket(outData,bytePacketSize);
                outputBuffer.get(outData,7,byteBufSize);

                m_aacDataQueue.add(outData);

                mEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);

                outputBuffer.clear();
            }
            outputBufferIndex = mEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);
        }
    }

    private void addADTStoPacket(byte[] packet, int packetLen) {
        int profile = 2;  //AAC LC
        int chanCfg = 1;  //CPE
        packet[0] = (byte) 0xFF;
        packet[1] = (byte) 0xF9;
        packet[2] = (byte) (((profile - 1) << 6) + (freqIdx << 2) + (chanCfg >> 2));
        packet[3] = (byte) (((chanCfg & 3) << 6) + (packetLen >> 11));
        packet[4] = (byte) ((packetLen & 0x7FF) >> 3);
        packet[5] = (byte) (((packetLen & 7) << 5) + 0x1F);
        packet[6] = (byte) 0xFC;
    }

    /**
     * release API
     */
    public void release() {
        try {
            m_threadRunning = false;
            m_aacEncodeThread.join();

            if (mEncoder != null) {
                mEncoder.stop();
                mEncoder.release();
            }
            clear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class AACThread extends Thread {
        private final static String TAG = "AACEncodeThread";

        private ThreadSleeper sleeper = new ThreadSleeper(64, TAG); // sleep 64millis

        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AAC encode thread start" );
            while(m_threadRunning){
                try {
                    sleeper.sleep(); // sleep 64millis
                    byte[] pcmData = m_pcmDataQueue.poll();
                    if(pcmData != null) {
                        encodeAAC(pcmData,0, pcmData.length);
                    }
                    pollEncoderResult();

                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "AAC encode thread stop" );
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Decoder code below.

```
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class AACDecoder {
    private static final String TAG = "AACDecoder";

    private int KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT = 2;

    private int KEY_SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;

    private int KEY_BIT_RATE = 64000;

    private MediaCodec mDecoder;

    private AtomicReference<AudioMixPlayer> m_mixPlayer = new AtomicReference<>(null);

    /**
     * set android audio player
     */
    public void setAudioMixPlayer(AudioMixPlayer audioMixPlayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "AACDecoder setAudioMixPlayer: " + audioMixPlayer);
        this.m_mixPlayer.set(audioMixPlayer);
    }

    private int freqIdx = 0xb;

    private Queue<byte[]> m_aacDataQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    private Queue<Object> m_sourceQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    private AtomicBoolean m_threadRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private AACThread m_aacDecodeThread;

    private String name;

    public AACDecoder() {
        this.name = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
    }

    /**
     * Init API
     */
    public void initCodec() {
        this.initCodec(16000, 1, 256000);
    }
    protected void initCodec(int sampleRate, int channelCount, int bitRate) {
        KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT = channelCount;
        KEY_SAMPLE_RATE = sampleRate;
        KEY_BIT_RATE = bitRate;
        switch (sampleRate) {
            case 96000:
                freqIdx = 0x00;
                break;
            case 88200:
                freqIdx = 0x01;
                break;
            case 64000:
                freqIdx = 0x02;
                break;
            case 48000:
                freqIdx = 0x03;
                break;
            case 44100:
                freqIdx = 0x04;
                break;
            case 32000:
                freqIdx = 0x05;
                break;
            case 24000:
                freqIdx = 0x06;
                break;
            case 22050:
                freqIdx = 0x07;
                break;
            case 16000:
                freqIdx = 0x08;
                break;
            case 12000:
                freqIdx = 0x09;
                break;
            case 11025:
                freqIdx = 0x0a;
                break;
            case 8000:
                freqIdx = 0x0b;
                break;
            case 7350:
                freqIdx = 0x0c;
                break;
        }
        prepare();
        m_aacDecodeThread = new AACThread();
        m_threadRunning.set(true);
        m_aacDecodeThread.start();
    }

    private boolean prepare() {
        try {

            String mine = "audio/mp4a-latm";

            mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mine);

            MediaFormat mediaFormat = new MediaFormat();

            mediaFormat.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, mine);

            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);

            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);

            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, KEY_BIT_RATE);

            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_IS_ADTS, 1);

            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);

            ByteBuffer csd = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
            csd.put(0, (byte) (MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC << 3 | freqIdx >> 1));
            csd.put(1, (byte) ((freqIdx & 0x01) << 7 | KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT << 3));
            mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd);

            mDecoder.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, 0);
            Log.d(TAG, "initCodec: " + mDecoder.getName());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Audio decode init error ", e);
            return false;
        }
        if (mDecoder == null) {
            return false;
        }
        mDecoder.start();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Decode API
     */
    public void decode(int source, byte[] buf, int offset, int length) {

        m_sourceQueue.add(source);
        m_aacDataQueue.add(buf);
        Log.d(TAG, "enqueue m_sourceQueue.size:" + m_sourceQueue.size() + " m_aacDataQueue.size:" + m_aacDataQueue.size() + " m_sourceQueue++ m_aacDataQueue++");

    }

    private void decodeAAC(byte[] buf, int offset, int length) {

        long kTimeOutUs = 0;
        try {
            boolean in = false;

            for (int triedTime = 1; triedTime <= 3; triedTime++) {

                int inputBufIndex = mDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(kTimeOutUs);

                if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {

                    ByteBuffer dstBuf = mDecoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);//codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                    if (dstBuf != null) {

                        dstBuf.clear();

                        dstBuf.put(buf, offset, length);

                        mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, length, 0, 0);
                        in = true;
                        Log.d(TAG, name + "》 Input success m_sourceQueue.size:" + m_sourceQueue.size() + " m_aacDataQueue.size" + m_aacDataQueue.size() + " inputBufIndex:" + inputBufIndex);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!in) {
                m_sourceQueue.poll();
                Log.d(TAG, name + "》 try 3 time but failed. poll one source. m_source m_sourceQueue.size:" + m_sourceQueue.size() + " m_aacDataQueue.size" + m_aacDataQueue.size() + " m_sourceQueue--");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Audio decode error ", e);
        }
    }

    private void pollDecoderResult() {

        long kTimeOutUs = 0;

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

        int outputBufferIndex = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);
        Log.d(TAG, name + "》 m_sourceQueue.size:" + m_sourceQueue.size() + " m_aacDataQueue.size" + m_aacDataQueue.size() + " try to pollDecoderResult " + info.size + " " + info.offset + " " + info.presentationTimeUs + " " + info.flags + " outputBufferIndex" + outputBufferIndex);

        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = mDecoder.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex);

            byte[] outData = new byte[info.size];
            if (outputBuffer != null) {
                outputBuffer.get(outData);

                Object source = m_sourceQueue.poll();

                Log.d(TAG, name + "》after pollDecoderResult m_sourceQueue.size:" + m_sourceQueue.size() + " m_aacDataQueue.size:" + m_aacDataQueue.size() + " outputBuffer.remaining:" + outputBuffer.remaining() + "  m_sourceQueue--");
                AudioMixPlayer mixPlayer = this.m_mixPlayer.get();
                Log.d(TAG, name + "》to addPcmFrame" + source + " length:" + outData.length);

                // play sound
                if (mixPlayer != null) {
                    mixPlayer.addPcmFrame(source, outData);
                }
                mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);

                outputBuffer.clear();
            }

            info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            outputBufferIndex = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);
        }
    }
    /**
     * release API
     */
    public void release() {
        try {
            m_threadRunning.set(false);
            m_aacDecodeThread.join();

            if (mDecoder != null) {
                mDecoder.stop();
                mDecoder.release();
            }
            m_mixPlayer.set(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "release error", e);
        }
    }

    private class AACThread extends Thread {
        //继承Thread类，并改写其run方法
        private final static String TAG = "AACDecodeThread";

        private ThreadSleeper sleeper = new ThreadSleeper(32, TAG); // sleep 32 millis

        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AAC decode thread start");
            while (m_threadRunning.get()) {
                try {
                    sleeper.sleep(); // sleep 32 millis
                    byte[] aacData = null;

                    if (!m_aacDataQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        aacData = m_aacDataQueue.poll();
                        Log.d(TAG, name + "》m_sourceQueue.size:" + m_sourceQueue.size() + " m_aacDataQueue.size:" + m_aacDataQueue.size() + " m_aacDataQueue--");
                    }

                    if (aacData != null) {
                        decodeAAC(aacData, 0, aacData.length);
                    }
                    pollDecoderResult();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "AAC decode thread error", e);
                    sleeper.reset();
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "AAC decode thread stop");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you figure out how to do it ?